# Android - Trying to get reference to a locally stored image with intent results in unexpected behavior

Tags: android, android-intent

**What should be happening:**

A user clicks on a button which brings up their phone's image gallery. They select an image via startActivityForResult, which I then get the path for and handle it from there.

**What is happening:**

When I click the button, the gallery opens up perfectly. But when I select an image, onActivityResult is never called and instead of closing the gallery and going back to the initial activity, the app goes back to the activity before it. Like it's calling onBackPressed or something.

My code for opening the gallery:

```
profilePicView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
}
```

Trying to get the result (this never gets called):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // none of this is every called, including the entire onActivityResult method
    if(requestCode == 1){           
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedProfilePicPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);            
    }
}
```

So all I'm trying to do is get the path to the selected image with onActivityResult. But that is never being called and for some reason this action causes the activity to go back to the previous activity. If it matters, this is an Activity and not a Fragment.

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` after launching the Intent to go to the Gallery? If so, don't. Also, is your `onActivityResult()` in an Activity or a Fragment?

Comment: I am not calling finish. This is an Activity

Comment: That's super weird. I assume you've tested this on more than one device?

Comment: Yep, but I've fixed it. Turns out it just won't work if you have "noHistory=true" defined in the Android Manifest.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had "noHistory=true" defined in the Android Manifest for this Activity. Removing that fixed everything.